# Eliminate small area pixel blobs of a two-value image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have tried to extract water body by calculated SDWI using Sentinel-1 images in Google Earth Engine :

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-81.19416175071366,42.14552897443303]);
var sentinel_col = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD");

var image = sentinel_col.filterDate('2020-05-01','2020-06-01')
                        .filterBounds(point);
var sdwi = image.map(function(img){
  var wi1 =img.expression('(10*VV*VH)',
                          {'VV':img.select('VV'),'VH':img.select('VH')})
                          .rename('Water1'); 
  var wi2 = wi1.log();
  var wi3 = wi2.expression('water-8',{'water':wi2.select('Water1')}).gt(0.35)
                          .rename('sdwi');
  return img.addBands(wi3) .select('sdwi')
});

Map.addLayer(sdwi,[0,1],'sdwi');
Map.centerObject(sdwi);
```

The result seems not bad, but there are lots of small area pixel blobs（similar to noises） in the result image.

I want to eliminate these numerous pixels without losing the detail of edge (so filter kernel ways were passed).

Although there is a function called "Segmentation Image" in ENVI have achieved my thought, I am still thinking if GEE could do the same process.

Answer (score 0):

You could do two rounds of convolutions with a low-pass filter. The first round effectively makes the white areas smaller, in doing so removes the isolated white pixels. The second round attempts to get those smaller white areas back to their original size (the isolated white pixels can't increase in size because they were removed in round 1). This is more likely to scale well than a reduceToVectors solution.

```
// try playing with these params
var smoothRadius = 50 // in meters
var thresh1 = 0.5
var thresh2 = 0.5

// make a mask for demonstration
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[27.51679088799306, 26.546401137051344],
          [27.51679088799306, 26.488032136842104],
          [27.61240627495595, 26.488032136842104],
          [27.61240627495595, 26.546401137051344]]], null, false);

var img = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .first() // a random image
  .select('B1')
  .lt(1000) // make a mask
  .clip(roi) // to speed things up
  
Map.addLayer(img, {}, 'original image')
Map.centerObject(roi, 13)

// define the low pass filter
var boxcar = ee.Kernel.square({
  radius: smoothRadius, units: 'meters', normalize: true
});

// apply the low pass filter to produce a smoothed image
var smooth1 = img.convolve(boxcar)
Map.addLayer(smooth1, {}, 'smooth1')

// make a binary image out of this
var smooth1Binary = smooth1.gt(thresh1)

// the result looks like the original, but the white patches are smaller
// note that the single pixels are gone
Map.addLayer(smooth1Binary, {}, 'smooth1 binary')

// Now to get back something similar to the original, use another round of low-pass filter
var smooth2 = smooth1Binary.convolve(boxcar)
Map.addLayer(smooth2,{}, 'smooth2')

// var doubleSmoothBinary 
var smooth2Binary = smooth2.gt(thresh2)
Map.addLayer(smooth2Binary, {},'smooth2 binary')
```

You can play around with the settings in the code editor to see what it looks like
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fcaseyengstrom%2Freprex%3Aboxcar

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce to vectors, and filter based on vector area. This is simple, but unlikely to scale well for larger datasets.

```
// try playing with these params
var geomMaxError= 10
var areaMaxError = 10
var vectorThresh = 10000 // in sq meters

// make a mask for demonstration
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[27.51679088799306, 26.546401137051344],
          [27.51679088799306, 26.488032136842104],
          [27.61240627495595, 26.488032136842104],
          [27.61240627495595, 26.546401137051344]]], null, false);

var img = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .first() // a random image
  .select('B1')
  .lt(1000) // make a mask
  .clip(roi) // to speed things up
  
Map.addLayer(img, {}, 'original image')
Map.centerObject(roi, 13)

// vector solution
var vectors = img.updateMask(img.eq(1)).reduceToVectors()
Map.addLayer(vectors,{},'all vectors')

var largeVectors = vectors
  .map(function(f){return f.set({size: f.geometry(geomMaxError).area(areaMaxError)})})
  .filterMetadata('size', 'greater_than', vectorThresh)
Map.addLayer(largeVectors, {}, 'large vectors')
```

Link to code editor: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fcaseyengstrom%2Freprex%3Aboxcar